# Divisibility by Quadratics $b^2+ba+1\mid a^2+ab+1\Rightarrow\ a=b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> The natural numbers $a$ and $b$ are such $a^2+ab+1$ is divisible by $b^2+ba+1$. Prove that $a = b$.

I tried to algebraically manipulate it as follows:

$(b^2 + ba + 1)k = a^2 + ab + 1$

$[b(a + b) + 1]k = a(a + b) + 1$

$kb(a + b) + k = a(a + b) + 1$

$k - 1 = (a - kb)(a + b)$

I'm stuck here. What should I do next? A case-by-case analysis of possible congruencies would be too tedious and inelegant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a^2+ab+1$ is divisible by $b^2+ba+1$, then so is $(a^2+ab+1)-(b^2+ba+1)=a^2-b^2$.

Note that $a+b$ and $b^2+ba+1$ are relatively prime. So $b^2+ab+1$ divides $a-b$. Now you should be able to finish, using considerations of size.

Comment: we can directly write: if $d|(a^2+ab+1),(b^2+ba+1)$  $d$ must divide $a(b^2+ba+1)-b(a^2+ab+1)=a-b$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Yes, I got there a slower way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: hi, i just have a question, can you help me a little bit more with how you continue from where you left off? $b^2+ab+1$ divides a-b

Comment: We have $0\le a-b$. Note that $ab\ge a\gt a-b$. So $b^2+ab+1\gt a-b$. The only way a "big" number like $b^2+ab+1$ can divide a number like $a-b$ which has smaller absolute value is if $a-b=0$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: and if we use your method, we can get d divides a-b, but does it mean that a-b=0? Thanks

Comment: @Akaichan: He reaches the conclusion $b^2+ab+1$ divides $a-b$, in a somewhat nicer way. The rest would be the same.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yes, I think I was being really silly :( Thank you though!